# Callback and observable in angular resolver

Tags: angular, callback, rxjs, observable

I'm using angular resolvers to provide data for my routes. For one of them, i need to get the lat and long for a given address string. To do that, i use the google geocode api :

```
service.geocode({address: params.address}, results => {
  params.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
  params.lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
});
```

So in my service i need to wait for the callback to fire before calling my apiService, so the main idea is to achieve this :

```
search(params): Observable<Calendar[]> {    
    return service.geocode({address: params.address}, results => {
          params.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          params.lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          return this.apiService.get('/api/v1/website/' + environment.web_id + '/calendar/_search', params)
          .pipe(map(
            data => {
              return data;
            }
          ));
    });
}
```

But i need to return an Observable so this won't work.
Is there a way to get an observable for the geocode callback and then use rxJs operators to chain them ?

Thanks !

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindCallback

Comment: do your code work fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is a way. The simplest step is to wrap the whole thing in an observable. A naive approach would be to do this:

```
search(params): Observable<Calendar[]> {
  // First, an observable. We get the observer back.
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    // Now go call your service.geocode (whatever that might be)
    service.geocode({address: params.address}, results => {
      // extend your params with the extra information.
      params.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      params.lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

      // shot the http request
      this.apiService.get('/api/v1/website/' + environment.web_id + '/calendar/_search', params)
        .pipe(
          map(data) => {
            // When the data is back, resolve it.
            observer.next(data);
            observer.complete();
          }),
        );
    });
  });
```

Now, we might do better and extract parts of this.

```
/** Make just the non-observable part observable. Then we can simply add it to the chain */
getLatLon(address): Observable<{lat: any, lon: any}> {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    service.geocode({address: params.address}, results => {
      // avoid side effects extra information.
      const lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      const lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        observer.next({ lat, lon });
        observer.complete();
  });
}
// Also

// Now you can use it in a regular chain.
search(params): Observable<Calendar[]> {
  return this.getLatLon(params)
    .pipe(
      map(coords => {
        // Again, we will avoid side effects.
        const fullParams = Object.assign({}, params, coords)
        return fullParams;
      }),
      map(fullParams => this.apiService.get(`/api/v1/website/${ environment.web_id }/calendar/_search`, params)),
    );
}
```

You could go further with this, but that's the basic.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways in which you can achieve this, (rxjs6)

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

and then create the observable from the value, like below:

```
of(someValue);
```

if you directly return someValue it will be a normal data, but if you use of operator from rxjs, you can convert that data into observable, and subscribe to it wherever required, Please modify your code accordingly, hope this helps